# Python Problems

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey guys I'm having ANOTHER problem with this python question.

A formula for computing Easter in the `years 1982 – 2048`, inclusive, is as follows:

let

```
a = year %19 
b = year %4 
c = year % 7
d = (19a + 24)%30
e= (2b + 4c + 6d + 5) % 7
```

The date of Easter is `March 22 + d + e` (which could be in April). Write a program that inputs a year, verifies that it is in the proper range, and then prints out the date of Easter that year. Additionally, write a function easterii() to do this. This function accepts no parameter and returns a value. Use a return statement.

This is the code that I have currently. When I enter in a date it always outputs `"There was a problem, try again."`

Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

```
def easterCal(year):
    a = year % 19
    b = year % 4
    c = year % 7
    d = ((19 * a) + 24) % 30
    e = ((2 * b) + (4 * c) + (6 * d) + 5) % 7
    date = 22+d+e
    return date

def easterii():
    try:
        year = eval(input('Please enter a year: '))

        year = int(year)


        if year < 1982:
            print("Year is out of range")
        elif year > 2048:
            print("Year out of range")
        else:
            date = easterCal(year)

        if 22 <= date <= 31:
            print('Easter date for year {0} is March,{1}'.format(year , date))

        elif  32 <= date <= 56: 
            print('Easter date for year {0} is April,{1}'.format(year,date-31))

        else:
            print('Incorrect.')

    except NameError:
        print('Please enter date in numbers')
    except:
        print('There was a problem, try again.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    easterii()
```

Comment: Why do you `eval()`? Also can you give an example of what you input

Comment: By using the `except:`, you are masking the real error message, making it much more dificult to find out what's going on. For production this is good, but while still debugging, i'd temporarily disbable it.

Answer (score 1):

One problem definitely is in this line:

```
year = eval(input('Please enter a year: '))
```

Why are you using `eval`? Just use `year = int(input('Please enter a year: '))`. If you enter a year correctly, your code will work (I tested it).

Comment: How do you know? We don't even know what he enters as input. If he enters a date it will fail on `int(year)`

Comment: Well, since his input prompt says "Please enter a year: " I dare to assume that he is correctly entering a year... Moreover: I tested his code with my correction and under my assumption.

Comment: He specificly states `When I enter in a date`, although I see your point

Comment: Oh I see your point now - I did not recognize that at first (I hope the last sentence in my answer provides more clarification)

Comment: Thanks Michael it definitely works! Thanks for all the input guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the traceback you would receive if you let exceptions propagate:

```
# input year out of range, e.g. 1952
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "...\test.py", line 23, in main
    if 22 <= date <= 31:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'date' referenced before assignment
```

the reason is that in your code in case of incorrect year you don't calculate `date`, but still reference it in `if` clause.

Proper code for `main` would be:

```
def main():
    year = int(input('Please enter a year: '))

    if 1982 < year < 2048:
        date = easterCal(year)
        if 22 <= date <= 31:
            print('Easter date for year {0} is March,{1}'.format(year , date))
        elif  32 <= date <= 56: 
            print('Easter date for year {0} is April,{1}'.format(year, date-31))
    else:
        print("Year is out of range")
```

Please note I've removed `try-catch` block, feel free to add it back again if you need to.

Comment: @user3521756 if it helps solving your problem don't hesitate upvoting an answer and accept it.

Comment: I would like to, but I don't have 15 reputation. I'm new to the site lol.

Comment: @user3521756 accepting answers doesn't require any reputation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you must provide a string to eval() as mentioned by the exception raised by your code:

```
eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object
```

in this line

```
year = eval(input('Please enter a year: '))
```

you can `str(eval(input()))`

note that you can print the exception by doing

```
except Exception, e:
  prtint e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dateEaster(year):
    if year >= 1900 and year <= 2099:
        a = year % 19
        b = year % 4
        c = year % 7
        d = (19 * a + 24) % 30
        e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d +5) % 7
        dateofeaster = 22 + d + e
        if year == 1954 or year == 1981 or year == 2049 or year == 2076:
            dateofeaster = dateofeaster - 7

        if dateofeaster > 31:
            dateofeaster = dateofeaster - 31
            print("April", dateofeaster)
        else:
            print("March", dateofeaster)
    else:
        print("There is an error")

year = int(input("Enter a year"))
dateEaster(year)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add a paragraph or two summarizing how your code addresses the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The Problem with your code was `eval`.There are few redundancies in your code like local variable `date` is referenced before assignment. Therefore it is wise to declare `date` as `global` and you can combine the `if` and `elif` together.

```
def easterCal(year):
    a = year % 19
    b = year % 4
    c = year % 7
    d = ((19 * a) + 24) % 30
    e = ((2 * b) + (4 * c) + (6 * d) + 5) % 7
    date = 22 + d + e
    return date


def main():
    global date
    try:
        year = int(input('Please enter a year: '))
        if 1982 < year > 2048:
            print("Year is out of range")
        else:
            date = easterCal(year)

        if 22 <= date <= 31:
            print('Easter date for year {0} is March,{1}'.format(year, date))

        elif 32 <= date <= 56:
            print('Easter date for year {0} is April,{1}'.format(year, date - 31))

        else:
            print('Incorrect.')

    except NameError:
        print('Please enter date in numbers')
    except:
        print('There was a problem, try again.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What have you changed? Why?. By just dumping code OP isn't learning that mutch.